# Foreach inside asp.net mvc5 view

Tags: asp.net, foreach, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm in need of a little help in here . I'm getting results that come from `virtual` property , but one row displays in multiple rows in `view`. How to display a record inside a row , and not in multiple records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Event.Id)
```

appears to be your problem. You're looping over the event ID, which since it's a string, will be treated like an array of characters. Therefore it prints one character from the ID on each line, and then, because of the rest of the code, repeats all the other details of that event on each line.

Since you only appear to have one single Event in your Model, it seems that you do not need any kind of loop here at all.

However it's not entirely clear what your intentions are - perhaps you intended to loop over something else in your model which is not shown. If so, please clarify the question and possibly the answer could be expanded.

Comment: sir it the same , i have edited the question , can you just take a look there in the image i posted

Comment: im trying to loop over the events items that a Home object has

Comment: re your edited code: `Model.Event.Id.Count()` counts the number of characters in your ID string. And as indicated by that code (I mean because you can directly access the ID property of the event), it's clear that you still only have _one_ Event object in your model. Do you understand about lists or arrays in C#?

Comment: sir , im trying to add more than 1 event per Home.Events are saved in this property        public virtual Event Event { get; set; } , in details view im trying to show all the events per specific Home. How to do that ? For example check how many events that home object has , than display them inside a table ..simple

Comment: in the picture i posted you can see , im getting the same (only for now) event object i 5 rows(event has 5 letters so there are 5 rows), how to display in 1 row ?

Comment: That property contains one single Event object. If you want multiple events in there you would need to define it as a list or array. List syntax would be something like `public virtual List<Event> Events { get; set; } ` and then populate it accordingly

Comment: "how to display in 1 row" - based on the existing code, simply remove the loop

Comment: @coffeaddict, this is a mess. In a previous question you published your  model "Home". I can see there the model has two properties, `Event` and `Events`. The former is just ONE event and the later is a List of events. Perhaps you should be iterating through `Model.Events` instead of `Model.Event`.

Comment: can you please sir edit your answer and tell me how to do that

Comment: @coffeaddict well I've shown you how to define the property in the comment. How you populate it is down to you, I have no knowledge of what your data source is or what you wish to put in it. To iterate through it, simply do a loop like `@foreach (Event item in Model.Events)`

Comment: No ,  i changed the model , how to iterate over the        public virtual Event Event { get; set; }
 property , lets say a Home object has 1000 Events , how to display them how to loop through them?

Comment: "how to iterate over the public virtual Event Event { get; set; } property". You can't. This property is a single item, it is **not a list** .

Comment: @coffeaddict No problem. I think you need to make a list instead, but I'm not sure...your model is bizarre - you have an EventID at the top level and seemingly some details about an event (e.g. location, facebook link etc). Then within that you have an Event object (or alternatively, you seem to want a list of events). Is there a master event with sub-events, or what? It's not clear what you're even trying to put on the page or how these things relate to each other. Also why did you just edit all the detail out of your question? Now it's not answerable or useful at all.

Comment: what you are talking , i did ..i posted another question here    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48278447/invalid-column-name-home-id-invalid-column-name-event-id-asp-net-mvc5-code    ..its a kind a weird model , im trying to map a many to many relationship between home and event classes , that just matter , home has an input field eventid that reads from event table the event name , what i need to do is be able for a Home object to create a list of events , and vice versa , but im getting this stupit error wholee day Invalid column name 'Home_Id'.
.thanks for explaining and time

Comment: @coffeaddict you edited this question to remove all the detail from it? Why? You should roll it back, otherwise it's hard for future readers to understand what the answer is about. Just because another question contains something similar makes no difference.